# window.getSelection() not working in android

Tags: android, html, webview, selection

I have a webview in android and inside it i am using the `window.getSelection();` method in order to get the height of the current cursor position from top of screen. Problem is that when I have pressed enter 5 times from keyboard of android it gives the correct height but when i go back to second line and again press enter it returns the height for sixth line i.e. the new `<br>` added in the end rather than the height of 3 line from top.

In short .. Suppose i have 5 line in total this function will return the height for the fifth line. but when i go to 2 line and press enter it have to return the height of third line from top but it gives me height for 6 line in android webview.

Code is down below. I want to calculate the `currentLine` i.e. on which line does the cursor is on.

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
if (sel.anchorNode != undefined) {
  if (sel.anchorNode.offsetTop != undefined)
    currentLine = Math.ceil(sel.anchorNode.offsetTop / lineHeight) + 1;
  else if (sel.anchorNode.parentNode != undefined && sel.anchorNode.parentNode.offsetTop != undefined)
    currentLine = Math.ceil(sel.anchorNode.parentNode.offsetTop / lineHeight) + 1;
 }
```

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: var sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.anchorNode != undefined) {
                if (sel.anchorNode.offsetTop != undefined)
                    currentLine = Math.ceil(sel.anchorNode.offsetTop / lineHeight) + 1;
                else if (sel.anchorNode.parentNode != undefined && sel.anchorNode.parentNode.offsetTop != undefined)
                    currentLine = Math.ceil(sel.anchorNode.parentNode.offsetTop / lineHeight) + 1;
            }